# Confused about handling data notification with onMessageReceived: is it called in a different thread? Why can it access global variables?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

In iOS, there is an extension called `NotificationService`. This is completely in a different 'target' and runs **next** to the main app in a different process. It can not access the main app's code. In that service, you can modify a notification, just before it's shown to the user.

This is different than Android's approach, where I can extend `FirebaseMessagingService`, override the `onMessageReceived` method and do whatever I want. I use `data` messages exclusivly. I have some questions about this method:

- Do I need to show a notification, or can I just do nothing and things keep working?
- Does `onMessageReceived` runs, just like in iOS, in a separate process, or in the same process as the app (if the app is open)?
- Why can I access global variables in my Service? From my local testing I see that the global variables are set to the same values when my app is running and reset when my app is closed, is there any documentation on this? When do they run in the same process?

Answer (score 0):

(** typical case: single process Application and FCM payload contains `title` and `body`)

1. It depends on various condition. but in typical case you have to handle it on your own **when your app is on foreground and received fcm push notification(this is the case when `onMessageReceived`  is called)**.
2. Typically nothing happens. But rarely `FirebaseMessagingService` itself can moved to Destroyed state when timeout reached.

3.It is called on FCM private background Thread. Also in typical case, since it's `Service` it share same process.( but you can run it on the other process)

4. In typical case, just send desired Intent using `LocalBroadCastReceiver` or dispatch event using some kind of static gloal field or method(cause your Activities and FirebaseMessagingService will run in same process).

below is detail about android's `FirebaseMessagingService`

FirebaseMessagingService have weird behavior and restriction.
(`FirebaseMessagingService` should run in same process where `com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver` runs.)
`onMessageReceived` is marked as `@WorkerThread` which means it's intend to be and will be called in background thread.

`FirebaseMessagingService` behavior depends on two condition

A - FirebaseMessagingService running process is Foreground
B - FCM payload contains only raw payload ( no `title` and no `body`)

If (B == true) or (A == true && B == false) than `onMessageReceived` is always called from FCM sdk's private workerThread and FCM SDK won't perfom any job to handle notification.

If (A == false && B == false) than `FirebaseMessagingService` handles the FCM payload by it self as FCM payload documentation mentioned and **won't call `onMessageReceived`**.

Answer (score 0):

Ad1: You don't need to show a notification on `onMessageReceived`. E.g. I had an app that only triggered background refresh of data for some notifications.

Ad2: Same process. [Services aren't run in separate processes by default](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).
(Unless you declare it with `android:isolatedProcess` option in the manifest, but it's a bit more than just an extra process.)

> [One of the most common uses of a Service is as a secondary component running alongside other parts of an application, in the same process as the rest of the components. All components of an .apk run in the same process unless explicitly stated otherwise, so this is a typical situation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#LocalServiceSample)

Ad3: They are run in the same process when the previous use of the process wasn't killed yet.

> ["This process is created for the application when some of its code needs to run and remains running until the system needs to reclaim its memory for use by other applications and it is no longer needed."](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)

In Android you have no guarantees over the process. Your `Activities` are state-saved in one process and then state-restored in another process and the app is supposed to continue like nothing happened. Because of that, global variables are unreliable in every scenario.

However, from personal experience, accessing a global variable from `FirebaseMessagingService` and then doing nothing if null or performing an action if present works good enough:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    override fun onTerminate() {
        instance = null
        super.onTerminate()
    }

    companion object {
        var instance: MyApplication? = null
            private set
    }
}

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        MyApplication.instance?.doSomething(message.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I stopped reading after I read `When your app is in background, onMessageReceived isn't even called at all, system creates a Notification from the data in the Message on its own.` because this simply isn't true for data messages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: @J.Doe yeah, that's why I prefaced it with "Following assumes that Message contains a Notification"

Comment: Ah ok, I though that applied only to the 3 'Ad'. Let me have another look

Comment: So the thing is that I am using messages with the `data` payload (which I did not mentioned enough in my question, let me edit that). Then, `onMessageReceive` is also called in the background. I am just curious in which process it rans, preferably with documentation.

Comment: I think Dianne Hackborn gives the best insight into the philosophy of android process management: http://web.archive.org/web/20180505121013/https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/FXCCYxepsDU
As I understand it, is that one can trust data in an `Activity`/`Service` from `onCreate` to `onDestroy`. It's more of `Activity` keeping the process alive, not the opposite. The process is a "no guarantees" area, subject to being killed by the system. Along with globals. But the state save/restoration is defined only for `Activity`. So globals cannot be trusted, unless they're self-restoring.

Comment: @J.Doe Why are you asking about global variables specifically?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have some questions regarding Android's approach to handling notifications and background services. Let me address your queries one by one:

1. **Do I need to show a notification, or can I just do nothing and things keep working?**

   In Android, when you receive a push notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), you have control over whether to show a notification or not. You can choose to handle the incoming message in your `onMessageReceived` method without displaying a notification. If you don't create and show a notification, the user will not see any visible indication of the message. So, yes, you can choose to do nothing with the notification, and your app will continue working without displaying it.
2. **Does onMessageReceived run in a separate process, or in the same process as the app (if the app is open)?**

   The `onMessageReceived` method of your `FirebaseMessagingService` runs in the same process as your app if the app is open. It executes within the context of your app's process. However, if your app is in the background or terminated, Android may launch your app's process to handle the message. In this case, the `onMessageReceived` method runs in a separate background process.
3. **Why can I access global variables in my Service? When do they run in the same process?**

   When you extend `FirebaseMessagingService` and override the `onMessageReceived` method, you have access to the app's global variables because you're running within the same process as the app. Android does not spawn a new process specifically for handling FCM messages; it utilizes your app's existing process.

   This is why you can access global variables, and their values are consistent with the app's state. When the app is running, the service operates in the same process, sharing the same memory space and variables. However, when the app is closed or not in memory, Android may create a new process for handling FCM messages, but it still initializes the necessary components, allowing you to access app-specific data.

Please note that while you can access global variables, you should be mindful of synchronization and threading issues to ensure that data is accessed and modified safely, especially if your app involves multi-threading or background tasks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).